# How can I import about 900 SMSs stored in about 50 folders into a phone running Lollipop / 5.1.1 whilst RETAINING the folder structure?

Tags: sms, file-management

Over the past few months I've successfully migrated from a Nokia 6220 Classic (running S60 3rd Edition software) to my current phone, a Sony Xperia Z, running Android Lollipop (5.1.1).

On the Nokia I have about 900 SMS text messages stored in about 50 folders. The folder structure is only one level deep, i.e. there are no sub folders within folders.

Through much research, trial and error, I was able to use Nokia Suite 3.8.54 to backup all the Nokia's content to my PC (or more precisely my Virtual PC - an emulated Windows XP environment running on my Mac).

I have the all the messages stored in a single ".csv" file (which opens fine in Microsoft Excel) as well as a copy of the database which Nokia Suite stored the messages in (a file called "msg_db.sqlite").

Additionally I was able to use NbuExplorer 3.3.88.40087 to extract the messages as individual ".vmg" files, retaining the folder structure. In other words I have around 50 folders on my Mac, each containing 1 or more messages, each being a ".vmg" file.

I've been able to use an app called VMG Converter:

http://www.animatedoak.com/apps/vmg-converter

to transfer one (or more) messages at a time to the Xperia phone. The paid for version of the app (VMG Converter Unlocker, £1.90) removes the 200 message limit on importing messages.

In theory I could use VMG Converter to import all 900 messages into the Messenger app on the Xperia, but I don't fancy 900 loose messages in my Inbox.

I want to import them whilst retaining the folder structure, but as far as I can make out, Android's default Messenger app & most similar apps don't support folders.

I can't for the life of me see why this is, and how on earth the lack of a directory / folder structure can in any way be seen as an "improvement". Perhaps this is just one more example of the dumbing down of user interfaces for the Facebook generation…

Anyway, most alternatives to the stock Android Messenger app seem to have juvenile features as their selling points (bright colours & so on).

I've only been able to find one app, called SMS Folders:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sms.organizer

that offers any sort of folder structure, but according to the reviews on the Google Play Store:

1. It's not possible to delete the default folders ("Work", "Personal", "Friends", "Family", etc).
2. It's not possible to move messages from one folder to another.
3. It's not possible to copy text from the messages, or forward the messages.
4. It's not possible to select more than one message at a time. There's no multiple selection option.
5. Crucially, it's not possible to move messages once they're in the Messenger app, only copy them.

So, SMS folders doesn't appear to be of much use in its current incarnation.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can import the messages whilst retaining the folder structure?

I also have a few MMS messages I'd like to import (in the form of ".mms" files & accompanying JPEGs & ".smil" files) but I'm happy to import these one at a time after I get the SMS messages imported, and then file them in their folders accordingly.

Many thanks.

---

Thanks for the reply. I'm having to add this comment to it as a continuation of my original question, as the "Add Comment" option has a pitiful character count limit, and also strips out all my carriage returns for some reason...

"To my knowledge Android SMS apps do not support folders for SMS messages but display and sort the messages in a threaded view based on the phone number of the contact."

Yes that certainly seems to be the way things work, mores the pity!

Even if I was to create Groups, without finding & installing an SMS app that can wrangle the messages based on the groups, then it wouldn't change anything.

"The SMS Folders app seems to be a SMS replacement app (You can only have one active SMS app)."

Yes that seems to be true, and yes my understanding is that you can only have one active SMS app.

"I actively maintain about 5000 SMS and 100 MMS on my phone at any given time."

How on earth do you do this? Is this on a non-smartphone like my old Nokia, or on an Android phone?

Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge Android SMS apps do not support folders for SMS messages but display and sort the messages in a threaded view based on the phone number of the contact. The solution may be to put your contacts in Groups, then some SMS app may be able to group them that way (the few I have used, Textra, CM Messaging, Google Messenger, Chomp SMS, do not support this). The SMS Folders app seems to be a SMS replacement app (You can only have one active SMS app). And BTW, 900 is nothing... I actively maintain about 5000 SMS and 100 MMS on my phone at any given time.